# Monit server went down

Tags: linux, monitoring, high-availability, monit

One of our developers needs some sort of notification in order to know whether the application is running smoothly or not.And We already decided that we will implement monit in order to get this things done.

Unfortunately,here comes another challenge. What happens if the monit itself went down?Surely they will not know whether their application is running or not?

Did anyone have any idea to make sure that this things can be notified (whether the server is going up or down)?

Thanks.

Comment: sorry..its monit.I must be getting old. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) typically does not die on its own. It's pretty stable/mature from that perspective.

If you use [M/Monit](http://mmonit.com/screenshots/), the relatively inexpensive central Monit console, you'll be able to poll the health of your individual Monit instances.

There is also the approach of running Monit from inittab/getty, respawning it automatically, but it's not necessary in my experience.

Edit:

Default Monit service messages:

```
Monit instance changed Service localhost

    Date:        Thu, 11 Oct 2012 05:17:13
    Action:      start
    Host:        OGC
    Description: Monit started

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

And:

```
Monit instance changed Service localhost

    Date:        Thu, 11 Oct 2012 05:17:09
    Action:      stop
    Host:        OGC
    Description: Monit stopped

Your faithful employee,
Monit
```

Comment: In the monit itself can it give us the email notification when the server is getting down (ie reboot) ? or do we need to configure something else?

Comment: By default, you will receive an email when Monit starts up and shuts down. See my update above.